# Angular JS - passing scope to stateful modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-strap

I am using angular js to develop my application. I am using angular router for routing and angular strap for modal dialog.

i have two states:

```
/admin/employees --> get all employees
/admin/employees/update:employeeId -->for edit a particular employee.
```

This is how my **dependencies** are configured:

```
var app = angular.module('pipeline', [
    'ngResource',
    'infinite-scroll',
    'angularSpinner',
    'jcs-autoValidate',
    'angular-ladda',
    'ui.router',
    'mgcrea.ngStrap',
    'toaster',
    'ngAnimate'
]);
```

**State provider configuration**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('pipeline', {
        url: '/pipeline',
        views: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'views/templates/pipeline.jsp',
                controller: 'PipelineController'
            },
            'buttonbar':{
                templateUrl: 'views/templates/button-bar.jsp',
                controller: 'PipelineController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('employees',{
        url: '/admin/employees',
        views: {
            'main':{
                templateUrl: 'views/templates/employee.jsp',
                controller: 'AdminController'
            },
            'search':{
                templateUrl: 'views/templates/search-form.jsp',
                controller: 'AdminController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('employees.add',{
        url: '/add',
        parent: 'employees',            
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', '$scope', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource, $scope){
            $modal({
                template: "views/templates/modal.edit.tpl.jsp",
                scope: $scope,
                show: true                  
            });
        }]
    })
    .state('employees.update',{
        url: '/update/:username',
        parent: 'employees',
        controller: 'EditEmployeeController',
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource){
            $modal({
                template: "views/templates/modal.edit.tpl.jsp",                 
                show: true                  
            });
        }]
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

**Controller for dialog**

```
app.controller('EditEmployeeController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, AdminService, $modal){
$scope.adminService = AdminService;
$scope.adminService.getSelectedEmployee($stateParams.username).then(function(){
    console.log("I am loaded.");
});

$scope.hideModal = function(){
    $modal.hide();
        $state.go("employees");
    };
});
```

**Service function to get employee**

```
'getSelectedEmployee': function(username){              
            var d = $q.defer();
            var entry = Employee.get({id:username, expand: true}, function(){                   
                self.selectedEmployee = new Employee(entry.employee);                   
                d.resolve();
            });
            return d.promise;
        }
```

**dialog from template**

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="form-control">{{ adminService.selectedEmployee.username }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="form-control"> {{ adminService.selectedEmployee.fullname }} </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="adminService.selectedEmployee.role.name">
            <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
            <option value="ROLE_FASTEST_USER">FASTEST USER</option>
            <option value="ROLE_EXTERNAL_USER">EXTERNAL USER</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Active</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="employeeActive" ng-model="adminService.selectedEmployee.active">            
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Save</button >
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" ng-click="hideModal()" >Cancel</button >
    </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to pass scope to this dialog and display value of selected employee.

Answer (score 0):

Create the modal on the EditEmployeeController controller since it has the $scope available.

Comment: Hi Asim, as from the code above posted, the employees are displayed on employee.jsp page... where I have provided them and edit link. The controller associated with them is 'AdminController'. So I gave ui-sref on that link for state navigation. If i open a modal from there, it will never be part of 'EditEmployeeController'. Isn't it?

Comment: Actually I am treating popup as a separate state. Earlier I crated popup from the AdminController it self and it worked. But then I realized while opening the popup it was changing my url backto '/#' the home page.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is your problem that you have to define the same functions on two controllers because you want to use a the modal in two places?

Comment: I want to create a popup on a state change from 'appurl/admin/employees' to 'appurl/admin/employees'. I am able create the popup successfully, but not getting scope variables..

Comment: How do i can share my sample application with you??

Comment: The best thing to do is to get everything in a http://plnkr.co/, for angular files just use a cdn like http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/ vs. uploading the files into plnkr but for your own stick them in plnkr.

Comment: Hi Asim, I hope you can download this plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/QsY9gWEcyvbQi0sRDgLU?p=preview . Do let me know that my design for edit contact functionality is correct or not? Also I am not sure the way I have created modal is correct. With plnkr modal isn't displaying correctly. if possible download the code. :)

Comment: So if you want to use a modal then there isn't any need to use a separate "state", thats why you're getting stuck. When choosing to use a modal you just create the modal form the main contacts controller and show it: http://plnkr.co/edit/GyOGhM8fvouNOPrAwwC7?p=preview - the other problem you had was the templateUrl param in the $model create function should infact just be "template".

Comment: I think you are right. Our browser url doesn't change on opening a dialog. I got over ambitious :| :|